# Backup fails to run

Tags: scadalts

On the current version 2.0.0 of Scada-LTS, if all you have is the admin user on the system then the full backup on the import/export page works. But as soon as you add a regular user to the system the backup fails to run when making a full backup. Does anyone else have this problem? Is this a bug or is there some way to fix this? Please if anyone else is having this problem let me know

Comment: Can you add the screens from the steps you take.